# Ruby on Rails - Search gem that fits my needs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a search gem and found searchkick really interesting.

I've got a few questions before implementing it

- Looked up the internet and didn't find anything about multiple resource search. Is it possible? For example: I have a model Post and User - can I search for them in just one search box?
- would this be a good idea in first case? would a search icon in the navbar make more sense? (click on it and get redirected to search page with multiple search boxes)

thanks

Comment: You can use sunspot https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi-search in Searchkick for this purpose.
https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#multi-search

Comment: You can also search across multiple indices if you want the results together instead of separate https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#multiple-indices

Answer (score 0):

Thats exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

In your Gemfile, for the last officially released gem:

```
gem 'ransack'
```

If you would like to use the latest updates (recommended), use the master branch:

```
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
```

And here's an article about how to use it basicly: https://medium.com/@jaspercurry/searching-and-sorting-on-rails-with-ransack-560e862e650a

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20503875)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-rails). you can work with only one search box for all of it.
it's a little complicated but it does support relations too

Comment: Note, you may also want to look at OpenSearch since the license for ElasticSearch has changed in recent years to be more restrictive and OpenSearch was created as a fully open sourced alternative. Should be a drop-in replacement. It more or less was when we made the conversion.